# How use token authentication with Rails, Devise and Backbone.js?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, backbone.js

I'm trying to build a mobile application with PhoneGap, jQuery Mobile and Backbone.js on the client-side - with a Rails 3 JSON API running server-side.

I know how to fetch the token from the server after being authenticated, but I don't know how to append the "token_auth" key/value to all the AJAX-requests Backbone.js will make to my server.

Here's my flow at the moment:

1. User types in some form fields and hits "Log in"
2. Backbone creates a new Player object with the email and password info.
3. I run a Player.authenticate that sets the token to AUTHENTICATION_TOKEN
4. All requests after this should append "auth_token=" + AUTHENTICATION_TOKEN

I've looked at http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Sync for maybe overriding the AJAX calls - but that seems quite extreme for this simple task.

Does anyone have any experience with running Devise token_authentication and Backbone.js?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Why don't append it to all of your jquery ajax requests. It will add the auth_token to all of your ajax calls over jQuery. That might be useful when working directly with jQuery ajax (or libs that do so). But this might be a security issue as well (when you have ajax calls to other sites...).

```
// this is untested
$.ajaxSetup({ beforeSend : function(xhr, settings){ 

  // just because the auth_token is a private information
  if(!settings.crossDomain) {

    // parse data object
    var dataobj = JSON.parse(xhr.data);

    // add authentication token to the data object
    dataobj.auth_token = AUTHENTICATION_TOKEN;

    // save the dataobject into the jqXHR object
    xhr.data = JSON.stringify(dataobj); 

  }
}});
```

---

Another approach may be to write that token into the header and process it on the server side:

```
// thats not beautiful
$.ajaxSetup({ headers : { "auth_token" : AUTHENTICATION_TOKEN } });
```

Comment: I really like this approach! It's descriptive and closer to what I'm trying to achieve! Thanks:)

Comment: Yes, approach is cleaner. However, there is not need to parse & stringify data, the authentication token can be sent using HTTP headers. Also, it's not needed on GET requests.
I updated the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dira/ZcY3D/18/

Comment: just for the future: is being able to authenticate through custom http headerfields a devise feature or is it rails-convention to list them on controller#params?

Comment: The authentication token would in this particular example be needed for ANY request to the server.

I don't think authenticating thru custom http headerfields is a feature in devise.

Comment: The header approach is the one to take, but please use the correct bearer token specification: 

http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-bearer-18   

Here is a sample header:

 GET /resource HTTP/1.1
   Host: server.example.com
   Authorization: Bearer mF_9.B5f-4.1JqM

PS: Sorry about the formatting - this is truy the most annoying editing box ever.

Comment: `$.ajaxSetup()` doesn't seem to include the header for non-ajax calls backbone makes to the server.

For example, if you reload a paper (which isn't ajax), the header isn't included.

Answer (score 27):

The key is to introduce it in the `Backbone.sync` method.

Take a look at this implementation: https://github.com/codebrew/backbone-rails/blob/master/vendor/assets/javascripts/backbone_rails_sync.js

You can add it yourself this way:

```
Backbone.old_sync = Backbone.sync
Backbone.sync = function(method, model, options) {
    var new_options =  _.extend({
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            var token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
            if (token) xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', token);
        }
    }, options)
    return Backbone.old_sync(method, model, new_options);
};
```

Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dira/ZcY3D/14/

Comment: This is a programmatically good way to solve the problem, but I like code that's a bit more closer to a textual "solution" for the problem. This will work though, I guess:)

Comment: Just wen't back to look at this question - and the reason this answer is not marked as accepted is because it uses the CSRF-token. Though one could just change the `var token =` line to make it work with any other variable.

Comment: dont forget return the old_sync "return Backbone.old_sync(method, model, new_options);" to keep the chaining and avoid problems on new backbone versions.

Answer (score 1):

Create a function like this that will send it any time an ajax request is sent to the server

```
$(function(){
    $(document).ajaxSend(function(e, xhr, options) {
        var token = $("meta[name='csrf-token']").attr("content");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-Token", token);
    });
})
```