# Ruby on Rails with Backbone - authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

I'm looking to write a single-page web application using RoR for the backend and Backbone (amongst other things) for the front-end. As with most things, the app will require the user to sign in (authentication easily handled with RoR and the database), but I'm confused as to how I would go about performing tasks with Backbone that require authentication. Because everything's client-side, it seems to me that I can't pass, for example, the user's ID to the backend as that'd be easy for somebody to discover.

Basically, how do I replicate a session-based authentication mechanism with Backbone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this post can help you [User Authentication with Rails and Backbone.js](http://42floors.com/blog/posts/user-authentication-with-rails-and-backbone-js)

Regards

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to look into token authentication: [How use token authentication with Rails, Devise and Backbone.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7785079/how-use-token-authentication-with-rails-devise-and-backbone-js)

Basically, you send login data and receive an authentication token that you then use in all subsequent ajax calls.

Users discovering their token isn't really an issue: they can log in and have legitimate access to the information.