# User Authentication using Devise, Backbone.js and Marionette.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, marionette

I'm using a pretty standard devise authentication setup in Rails 3.2 using token_authenticatable.  It works great, but I've decided to re-write my application using backbone.js and marionette.js for a richer client-side javascript environment.

I guess my main question is how do I go about accessing the current user token through client-side javascript in a backbone view?

I've read through this: [How use token authentication with Rails, Devise and Backbone.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7785079/how-use-token-authentication-with-rails-devise-and-backbone-js) but I don't really understand the approved answer.