# Store text from the DOM into Rails model using Backbone

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

I've been working on a small app using Rails4 and Backbone.js. So far I've got a sign up/login system going, and users can make a list of movies they have seen by defining the movie title in a input field that stores the movie title in a Movie model and shows the movies the user made in the view.

But I don't like the fact that users have to reload their page to see the result, that's why I want to use Backbone in my project. For that I'm using the `'backbone-on-rails'` gem.

So far I've created a view

```
class Movieseat.Views.MovieseatsIndex extends Backbone.View

  template: JST['movieseats/index']

  initialize: ->
    @render()

  render: ->
    @$el.html @template()

  events: -> 
    "click li": "showtext"

  showtext: (e) ->
    movietitle = $(e.target).text()
    console.log  movietitle

  el: "#container"
```

That renders a template,

```
<ul id="movie-overview">
    <li class="movietitle">Star Wars 1</li>
    <li class="movietitle">Star Wars 2</li>
    <li class="movietitle">Star Wars 3</li>
    <li class="movietitle">Star Wars 4</li>
    <li class="movietitle">Star Wars 5</li>
    <li class="movietitle">Star Wars 6</li>
    <li class="movietitle">Star Wars 7</li>
</ul>

<div>Not star wars</div>
```

On my homepage

```
:javascript 
  $(function() { 
    new Movieseat.Views.MovieseatsIndex
  });

#container
```

As you can see the view has a click event on a li element. When that happens it shows the text from that li element in the console.

What I want to do is save the text from the li (the console output) into my rails Movie model. I've looked at the [RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/325-backbone-on-rails-part-2) but he's using a form, and I can't find a example on how to save text into my Rails model. What kind of event could do that? And would I need to use collections and models to make this dynamic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I will suggest you to use [Marionette](http://marionettejs.com/) with [Backbone](http://backbonejs.org/) which will give a good structure to your application and it's modules/sub modules.

---

For your issues in it's present state you could use `Backbone.Model` to interact with back end (Rails).

**1.** You need to create movies resource if you need all CRUD verbs or just one route with POST method.
To save time just generate your resource with scaffold generator. 
Type in console `rails g scaffold movies title:string duration:integer lang:string`.

This will generate all needed files (Controller, Views, Model) for you with appropriate actions for CRUD. In your routes.rb you will see something like:

**routes.rb**

```
YourApplicationName::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :movies
  # A lot of other routes including root
end
```

After run migrations with `rake db:migrate`. Back end ready!

Now in your front end javascript source add new backbone model:

```
var  MovieModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: 'domain_path.com/movies', 
    defaults: {
       title: '', 
       duration: '',
       lang: ''
    } 
});
```

and in your `showtext` method:

```
showText: function(e) {
    var movie_title = $(e.target).text()
    movie = new MovieModel();
    movie.set('title', movie_title);
    movie.save();  
}
```

Here `movie.save()` will trigger `POST` request to `/movies` which will create new Movie model with title. This is the simplest solution for your issue. And be sure to set authenticity_token in ajax header, in other way rails will throw error (but it could be included in gem you using, I haven't used it). [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7785079/how-use-token-authentication-with-rails-devise-and-backbone-js) nice post regarding it.

Please try and let me know if it works.

Comment: Would you advice using Marionette to someone who´s still learning the basics of Backbone? A question about the rootUrl, is it needed to post the domain name? Because I'm working locally now but once it goes live the url would change.

Comment: I'm getting a error in my console `Uncaught ReferenceError: MovieModel is not defined`. I've added your code into my model file, resulting in the following code.

`class Movieseat.Models.Movieseat extends Backbone.Model

  MovieModel = Backbone.Model.extend(
    rootUrl: "movies"
    defaults:
      title: ""
      duration: ""
      lang: ""
  )`

Comment: By the way, I've already created a Movie model in Rails in which I have a collumn `title`.

Comment: @PeterBoomsma Yes you could learn backbone from Marionette as well.  Regarding my answer - I have typo there, I just updated it, `rootUrl` -> `urlRoot`. And urlRoot could be a function also. You could check for `env` and return needed url for your `urlRoot`.

Comment: Could you post your Backbone.Model source code? I guess some 'var' declaration(s) missing.

Comment: It doesn't mather if I put in any code in my app > assets > javascripts > models > movieseat.js.coffee file. If it's empty I'm also getting the `Uncaught ReferenceError`. So it looks like my View doesn't know where my Model is.

Comment: How you managing file's load (order of load in application.js)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63230/discussion-between-peter-boomsma-and-vahan-vardanyan).

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Vahan Vardanyan we got the following solution.

The Backbone View

```
class Movieseat.Views.MovieseatsIndex extends Backbone.View

  template: JST['movieseats/index'] 

  initialize: -> 
    @render() 

  render: -> 
    @$el.html @template() 

  events: -> 
    "click li": "showtext" 

  showtext: (e) -> 
  # Creates a variable storing the text of the event target
    movie_title = $(e.target).text() 
  # Creates a new instance of the Movieseat (project name)model
    movie = new Movieseat.Models.Movieseat() 
  # Sets the content of the variable movie_title in the title collumn in the movie model
    movie.set('title', movie_title)
  # Save action
    movie.save() 

  el: "#container"
```

The Backbone model

```
class Movieseat.Models.Movieseat extends Backbone.Model

# Which model the data needs to be saved
  urlRoot: "movies" 
# What data needs to be saved
  defaults: 
    title: ""
```

Comment: Just rewriting my answer with CoffeScript doesn't make it better.